# 4.7v as HIGH on digital output instead of 5v

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm new to Arduino, just got my starter kit, and I noticed that digital outputs 3 & 4 have 5v as HIGH level while 5 to 13 have 4.7v as HIGH level.
Is it as it suppose to be?

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: Please add your code so that we can check that there isn't a problem there.

Answer (score 2):

Also depends on what your driving via this output. Standard TTL is:

[image]

But CMOS will be a bit different:

[image]

Comment: The Arduino is connected to USB port of MacBook pro. I wrote simple code to check HIGH level on digital pins: 
`void loop() {

  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}`

Comment: Are those pins output? @d.a.  Please amend your question to post your entire code. You may also want to read up on how to make a loop.

Comment: @NickGammon as a point there.

Instead of putting that in loop(), of that in setup() and do the same readings to see if you have the same voltages.

Comment: I should point out, that after I tested, I noticed you omitted pin 9 from your list. A loop wouldn't have had that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's perfectly fine.

According to the datasheet, at 5V, the minimum voltage you can expect on a HIGH output (AKA V<sub>OH</sub>) is 4.2V. 4.7V is above that, so it's fine.

Comment: Thanks. That was weird for me, because 1 hour ago it was showing 5v to me. And I do not understand what changed.

Comment: Maybe the battery in your meter is running out?

Comment: Also if it is set to `INPUT_PULLUP` it will look HIGH but maybe with a lower voltage (depending on the impedance of your meter)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers here suggest that a reading of 4.7V is in spec (which it is). As Majenko says, 4.2V is the minimum output high voltage, at an ambient temperature of 85°C, with a load of 20 mA, and Vcc = 5V.

*However* with no load, and at room temperature, I measured 4.99V on all of those pins, when set to `OUTPUT` and `HIGH` on *my* Uno. Test code:

```
void setup() 
{
for (int i = 3; i <= 13; i++)
  pinMode (i, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() 
{
for (int i = 3; i <= 13; i++)
  digitalWrite (i, HIGH);
}
```

> That was weird for me, because 1 hour ago it was showing 5v to me.

Right. What were you doing an hour ago? Did you have LEDs connected to those pins? If so, what value resistor did you have in series with them? Or were you driving a motor from the pins perhaps?

Comment: Thanks everybody for help, I forgot to set pin 5 as OUTPUT. When I dit it, I got 5v on it.